# JavaFX MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE in JAR file

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, executable-jar

I'm currently trying to get the JavaFX media player to work and have some strange behavior with locating my media files when packing my application. It works just fine when running it in eclipse but as soon as I pack it with maven as a one-jar the media file can no longer be found and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : \resources-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.one-jar.jar     
(Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at javafx.scene.media.AudioClip.<init>(AudioClip.java:65)
    at com.example.test.MyResourceTest.getResource(MyResourceTest.java:11)
    at com.example.test.MyResourceTest.main(MyResourceTest.java:18)
    ... 6 more
```

The error reason states that the system can't find the given file. Funny thing is that it is actually available inside the one-jar file and therefore it should work. This is kind of a show stopper for me and I couldn't get a single response from the Oracle forum.

I uploaded my simple eclipse project for anyone to try:
http://www.fileswap.com/dl/itytDY7mcY/

Otherwise this is the code:

```
public class MyResourceTest {

    public String getResource() {
        final URL sound = getClass().getResource("/com/example/data/sound.mp3");
        AudioClip soundEffect = new AudioClip(sound.toString());
        return sound.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new MyResourceTest().getResource());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found a really nice way to solve this
use:

```
 getHostServices().getDocumentBase()
```

in your application class to get the documentbase,
then use something like

```
 Media media = new Media(documentBase + "/resources/" + name + ".mp3");
 player = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

or in your case:

```
Media media = new Media(documentBase + "/com/example/data/sound.mp3");
player = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

(this only works if you're using a javafx application)